# Select group of columns from an excel/csv file in R

Tags: r

I have a csv file of 100 columns. I would like to select columns in group of 4 and generate a new file. If it's not clear, have columns from 1-4 in a new file, then 4-8, 8-12 etc. Basically from 1 to 100 with 4 step size. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The `{purrr}` package can make it easy:

```
# import your original csv file
my_file <- read.csv("filename.csv")

# create an auxiliar list
colnumbers <- 1:100
colsplits <- split(colnumbers, ceiling(colnumbers/4))

# walk through it
purrr::iwalk(
  colsplits,
  ~ write.csv(my_file[, .x], paste0(.y, ".csv"))
)
```

This code will create 25 files in your working directory named "1.csv", "2.csv", ..., "25.csv".

Comment: Thank you so much. After that, I created a list with list.files(pattern="*.csv") and file_list<-lapply(list_of_files, read_csv, col_names = TRUE). Do you know can I apply the same function to all the files in the list? I tried with function(df) but it doesn't work. I need to rename all the columns and concatenate two of them inside of all files.

Comment: Glad I've helped. You can open a new question with that different problem.